# In TypeScript, is there a way to create a generic mixin function, that also allows a generic type parameter on the returned class?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to hopefully get this mixin working, but I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is even supported by TS.

Is there any way to pass the `<T>` from `GenericChild` to the returned class from `Mixin1`? Or is there a way I can restructure/refactor to get a similar result?

Currently, there is a compiler error for this code: `"A mixin class must have a constructor with a single rest parameter of type 'any[]'."`. (it also says `prop2` doesn't exist on the type, but I think that will be fixed if I get past the first error)

Code:

```
class BaseClass1 {
    prop1 = 'baseClass1';
}

class BaseClass2 extends BaseClass1 {
    prop2 = 'baseClass2';
}
class GenericChild<T> extends Mixin1(BaseClass2)<T> {
    childProp: T | undefined = undefined;
}

type Constructor<T> = new(...args: any[]) => T;


function Mixin1<T extends Constructor<BaseClass1>>(Base: T) {
    return class <TResult> extends Base {
        anonResult: TResult | undefined = undefined;

        constructor(...args: any[]) {
            super(...args);
        }
    };
}

class Child1 extends GenericChild<string> {
    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log(this);
    }
}

console.log(new Child1().prop2);
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.3.3&ssl=8&ssc=43&pln=10&pc=2#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFMDC4oEZoG8CwAoaB0ADgE4D2RGAvNAOQBGiKkEatA3HgL556gtwmqCACZoCAB4AXBADsAJjHgRkwjDnyFSFMTQZCWIjtz7DoAcTkISAS2BIAFjZDyAPABUAfOOlzF0AFkbCRtZNAAKZVVDAEoPbw1CaGAnFwAFciIALmh3aAAfaABXBQQAM1CEeWgaEvlyyvlOXB5cPCkATyIEaCQyWQgpEiLgKTISeJroWQQAd3CAOiWwEgBzCBywWQ6AbQBdGJrvd2beXDKS0Zt+wODQtA8fGQUYPoGhkbGJqOZ0T09Iogcu5DolCCQEFIiiRZMkzB4AEoICBFEBSbySZ7+KJYPBJJJbfpIlFo4HE1FSArFUoVGbVWo0xqnTT45L9QbDUbjRbLNYbaBbXYHXEs1mEFHdEg8hYrdYxZpi6CtJJcZqtUwCRzOeQYTF+GCWGa2eypNwc0KrBJ4wjAdkfLlS0HW1kS6zheXO-G2gZkEAIBYgMircJSJwQD2i1rq3DeiC+-2B4MzWa9U0RGILbREETyoA)

I want instances of `Child1` to be able to access `prop1`, `prop2`, `childProp`, and `anonResult`. I realize that I can just have `Child1` compose these classes, but I want to see if this is possible with a mixin, so the properties will be available directly off the `Child1` instance.

Also, I read through [this TS issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26154), but I don't think it really covers what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Does [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFMDC4oEZoG8CwAoaB0ADgE4D2RGAvNAOQBGiKkEatA3HgL54AuAnkQTQkZAHYReJAK7BeZEgB4AKgD5oNMQgDu0ABQA6I2BIBzCAC5oYMfwDaAXQCUG9cs64AZtLFyAluLQALJ+AB5+Ymgq0AihvAhiACYwohJSsvJK8BDIqKyqqnrZCFbKLjj4hAJC0ACSaTbACCoASuo0mNZi4i0IENIgvKUt0AA+0D6JCJ4RCInQXNAAZHUNvgjKgs1qHoTQJAi80iRi0KAsMXEJyXCIWHh7ezY9fQO8GhNJ07OJu48EwHEkhkcgUhmMZksXXsznulX+e36QhI4IMJnMTj+-x48IW1hgNn4+Kw0DsAGloBFoABrBD8MieaDKBxWCmxeJJGAAIlIZHk1QQXOgAH5VpJGs0fNTutoxOpSuSHHilg8EXotLpWoUjGjIVZUsCMgoAAomMAAW0OCBIEBUqhcVHU9XF6y1mO4eCAA) work for you?